# I have problem about pointing in discord py

Tags: python, sqlite, discord.py

i am making pointing system in discord.py. I am using sqlite3 database and i have following problem:

````
async def solved(ctx, member : discord.Member):
    c.execute(f'SELECT name FROM math WHERE name = "{member.name}"')
    checkname = c.fetchone()
    if checkname == member.name:
        c.execute(f"INSERT INTO math VALUES('{member.name}', 40, '{ctx.guild.id}')")
        await ctx.send("User is in database")

        c.execute(f"SELECT qula FROM math WHERE name = '{member.name}'")
        qula = c.fetchone()
        print(qula)
        saboloo = int(qula[1]) + 40
        c.execute("UPDATE math SET qula = ? WHERE name = ?", (saboloo, member.name)) 
        await ctx.send("You earned 40 coins.")
        print(checkname)
    elif checkname != member.name:
        print(checkname)
        c.execute(f"INSERT INTO math VALUES('{member.name}', 40, '{ctx.guild.id}')")
        await ctx.send("User is not in database")```

Every time I type this command, the bot says that the user is not in the database.
````

Answer (score 1):

You should use member.id not member.name - they can change their nickname anytime but id stays the same. That may cause you some problems

Try using this:

```py
c.execute(f"SELECT name FROM math WHERE name='{member.name}'")
```